# Gem environment/install location and bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

it's been a while since I setup a brand new Rails environment.

I am trying to get gems to install under ~/.gems as opposed to /usr to avoid sudo-ing constantly.

Here is my gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/myname/.gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/myname/.gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/myname/.gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "gemhome" => "/home/myname/.gems"
     - "gempath" => ["/home/myname/.gems"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/

$ which bundle
/home/myname/.gems/bin/bundle
```

now I did `rails new SomeApp` and when I run
*bundle install*

I get:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/build_info/jquery-rails-3.0.4.info
An error occurred while installing jquery-rails (3.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue
```

Which tells me that it's still trying to install the gem NOT where I want it. Any thoughts what to check? (I do have a ~/.gemrc file, the contents are the last 3 lines of the GEM CONFIGURATION section above).

Many thanks for all tips -- this was supposed to be a quick and easy step :)

Comment: I would look into using RVM or rbenv: rvm.io and rbenv.org

Comment: highly recommend rbenv and rbenv-gemset:
brew install rbenv rbenv-gemset
echo specialgemsetname > .rbenv-gemsets

Answer (score 0):

highly recommend rbenv and rbenv-gemset, installing here with homebrew:

```
brew install rbenv rbenv-gemset
cd into/project/
echo specialgemsetname > .rbenv-gemsets
```

now start a new terminal (to ensure environment is correct) and setup your project.